# What is the machinery depicted in the Metroid Prime Trilogy intro sequence?

Tags: nintendo-wii, metroid-prime-trilogy

[The intro video of Metroid Prime 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKMKLH5pX7Y) has the camera backing out through a tunnel full of machinery. Is it known what this is? Is it the interior of Samus's arm cannon?

If this is a spoiler, please mark it as such; I have not completed Metroid Prime 3.

Comment: [Youtube video of the opening sequence + main menu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTZFQrun1QY#t=34s).

Comment: Hm. Arm cannon seems likely.

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs Thanks. Linking a video seems a good idea but I didn't want to link into the middle of a really long one, so I found a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a spoiler. It's the internal workings of her arm-cannon charging and firing a shot, shown in slow motion. Samus is in the middle of the final battle of Super Metroid, fighting Mother Brain.

[Edit] See comment below!

Comment: Are you saying that Super Metroid has a similar scene?

Comment: No, Super Metroid doesn't have a similar scene; it's a different take on the same scene.

Comment: Oh you know what? I'm getting this mixed up with Other M! Alright it's still Samus' arm cannon, but it actually doesn't depict Mother Brain in the Metroid Prime series. Sorry about that. As to your question in the comments, the Cutscene I was referring to before (in Other M) is based off the last boss fight of Super Metroid (which does include a short in-game cutscene.) The Menu sequence for the Trilogy opening does show the same thing, though: Samus' arm cannon forming a shot in slow motion as the camera pans backwards to the outside. :)